# three js - raycaster failing

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a mesh defined which is at the origin.

```
var textureCanvas = new THREE.CanvasTexture( imageCanvas );
textureCanvas.repeat.set( 4, 4 );
textureCanvas.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
textureCanvas.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

var materialCanvas = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: textureCanvas } 
);

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3(-4,-4,0),
    new THREE.Vector3(-4,4,0),
    new THREE.Vector3(4,4,0),
    new THREE.Vector3(4,-4,0),
);

geometry.faces.push(                    
    new THREE.Face3(3, 1, 0),
    new THREE.Face3(3, 2, 1)
);

var vertexMappings = [];
vertexMappings[0] = new THREE.Vector2(0,1);
vertexMappings[1] = new THREE.Vector2(0,0);
vertexMappings[2] = new THREE.Vector2(1,0);
vertexMappings[3] = new THREE.Vector2(1,1);
var vm = vertexMappings;

geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ] = [];
geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][0] = [ vm[3], vm[1], vm[0] ];
geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][1] = [ vm[3], vm[2], vm[1] ];                

meshCanvas = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materialCanvas );
meshCanvas.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 3;
meshCanvas.rotation.z = - Math.PI / 2.5;

meshCanvas.scale.set( 80, 80, 80 );

scene.add( meshCanvas );
```

I also have a line which goes through the mesh. It was originally passing through the origin but I moved it a bit (See github issue below).

```
var linegeo = new THREE.Geometry();
linegeo.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3(55, 300, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(-10, -300, 32)
);

scene.add(linemesh);
```

I want to get the position where the line intersects the mesh, but the intersections result is always empty:

```
getInersectionPosition(linemesh, meshCanvas);


function getInersectionPosition(linemesh, meshCanvas) {
    linemesh.updateMatrixWorld();
    meshCanvas.updateMatrixWorld();

    var p1 = linemesh.geometry.vertices[0].clone(),
    p2 = linemesh.geometry.vertices[1].clone();

    p1.applyMatrix4(linemesh.matrixWorld);
    p2.applyMatrix4(linemesh.matrixWorld);

    //console.log(`p1: ${JSON.stringify(p1)}, p2: ${JSON.stringify(p2)}`);
    //console.log(`canvas position: ${JSON.stringify(meshCanvas.position)}`);

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(p1, p2);
    raycaster.linePrecision = 10;

    //var intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects([meshCanvas]);
    var intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);

    if (intersections.length > 0)
        console.log(`intersections: ${ intersections.length}`);
}
```

Full sample: https://jsfiddle.net/mribbons/103wwsda/

Is it possible that I have this issue? 
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/11449

The raycaster.intersectObjects() call seems to fail here, with very large values for distance (2.7 million or so, while sphere.radius is ~450).

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/build/three.js#L9761

```
intersectsSphere: function ( sphere ) {
    var distance = this.distanceToPoint( sphere.center )

    return distance <= sphere.radius;

},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, raycaster expects a point and a normal, this resolves the issue:

```
var normal = new THREE.Vector3();

normal.subVectors(p2, p1).normalize();

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(p1, normal);

var intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);

if (intersections.length > 0)
    console.log(`intersections: ${ intersections.length}`); // outputs "intersections: 2"
```